# Gulp vinyl-ftp remote download not working

Tags: ftp, gulp, vinyl-ftp

I'm trying to download the remote test folder to my local project with vinyl-ftp

```js
gulp.task('ftp', () => {

  var conn = ftp.create({
    host: host,
    user: username,
    password: password,
    parallel: 10,
    log: gutil.log,
  });

  conn
    .src('/websites/www/www.example.com/HTML/test/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./test'));
});
```

This is the respond I get

```
[10:50:40] Using gulpfile \Desktop\gulp\gulpfile.js
[10:50:40] Starting 'ftp'...
[10:50:40] CONN
[10:50:40] READY
[10:50:40] MLSD /websites/www/www.example.com/HTML/test
[10:50:40] GET \websites\www\www.example.com\HTML\test\test.txt
[10:50:40] 'ftp' error after 396ms
[10:50:40] Error: \websites\www\www.example.com\HTML\test\test.txt: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Umm, does vinyl-ftp download or upload only?  You might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/download

Comment: it uploads just fine but thanks for that link I'll try it out in a bit

Comment: Yes, I think `vinyl-ftp` is designed to upload, not to download.